# I am getting ';' expected error,illegal start expression and else without if

Tags: java-6

i want to out put like this-

150 can be fitted in:

- short
- int
- long

150000 can be fitted in:

- int
- long

1500000000 can be fitted in:

- int
- long

213333333333333333333333333333333333 can't be fitted anywhere.

-100000000000000 can be fitted in:

- long

  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.*;
  import java.text.*;
  import java.math.*;
  import java.util.regex.*;

  public class Solution {

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
      byte b;
      long l;
      int t, v;
      int[] n;
      Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Inter the number");
      v=in.nextInt();
      n=new int[v];
      int i=0;
      while(n.hasNextInt())
          {
          n[i]=in.nextInt();
          i++;
      }
      for(int k=0;k<t;k++)
          {if(b<n[k])
            {  
              System.out.println(k+"this is fit in");
              System.out.println("*short");
              System.out.println("*int");
              System.out.println("*long");}
           else if(t==n[k]){
              System.out.println(n[k]+"this is fit in");
              System.out.println("int");
           System.out.println("long");}
          else if(t<=n[k]){
              System.out.println(n[k]+"this is fit in");
              System.out.println("int");
              System.out.println("long");}
          else if((t<=n[k])&&(l==n[k])){
              System.out.println(n[k]+"this is fit in");
              System.out.println("long");}
          else{
              System.out.println(n[k]+"this not fitted any where");}}}}
  ```

Comment: *My eyes!* Why in heaven's name would you hide the `}` at the end of the last statement in a block? Why? Why?

Comment: Please use correct grammar and formatting to make your question more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I expect it's the fact you have no logical join (`&&` or `||`) and value here:

```
else if(t<=n[k]>){
// ------------^
```

Also note that the type `int[]` has no `hasNextInt` method, so this line:

```
while(n.hasNextInt())
```

won't compile (as `n` is `int[]`).

There are about a half dozen other logic errors in there (using uninitialized variables, etc.), but hopefully that gets you headed the right way.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to use an IDE like eclipse or netbeans that formats your code and makes life far easier to debug, develop in open-source and reduces the development time. 
Coming to the errors: I can spot that you have missed a } at the end of the program script and I notice a syntactically wrong statement:

```
} else if (t <= n[k] > ) {
```

Please confirm to correct syntactically code and use formatting to enable fellow developers help you. Good luck!

Comment: No, there is no missing `}` in the code. Yes, there is a problem with that line -- which I pointed out 20 minutes ago.